# Is any way to change control's background color without `BackColor` property?

Tags: c#, controls

There are some properties for Controls, that needs `System.Drawing.dll` to be used, i.e.:

```
control.Size =  new System.Drawing.Size(10, 20);
```

however, that goal can be achieved without with other workaround (not needed `System.Drawing`), i.e.:

```
control.Width = 10;
control.Height= 20;
```

My question is, can we change control's background color ( `.BackColor`, which requires `System.Drawing`)  with some workarounds like that? (so, not needed `System.Drawing`)?

Comment: What's the problem with using System.Drawing? To answer the question, no, since there's no other property that sets the background color and the type of that property is `System.Drawing.Color`.

Comment: @DStanley please post your comment as answer, without the first question part please. I am overly tired of contr-questions `why you need..` kind. There is reason. 
 thanks, i will accept the answer.

Comment: If "no" is the answer you're looking for I'll do that - I'm more curious what your aversion to `System.Drawing` is since that's the obvious solution. Or I can provide an alternate _syntax_ that doesn't use `System.Drawing` directly (e.g. a `using` directive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - The dependency on `System.Drawing` is for the `Color` value itself and there are no shortcut properties to, for example, set the component values like you can with `Size`.

If you don't want to include `System.Drawing` inline just add a `using` directive:

```
using System.Drawing;

...

    control.BackColor = Color.Blue;  // Color will be found in System.Drawing via the "using"
```

Comment: just the `System.Drawing.dll` should not be referenced in any way :)) that was the whole point, not the way how to reference that.

Comment: `System.Drawing.dll` is a dependency of `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and `System.Web.dll` so it's already referenced indirectly.